# Short story describing computer-controlled society ending up with the computer's demise

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, computers

I am looking for a story, probably from the early 1950's, about a society that was essentially controlled by a computer. Every person had a plastic cube that contained their history.  If one wanted to make a "important" decision, they had to get permission from the computer.

Everything went well for awhile but then became so complex that the computer had a melt-down. One might even assert that the computer was the forerunner of AI.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall if you read this in an anthology or a magazine?  Was the society worldwide, or merely regional (e.g. North American continent) in size?

Comment: it is interesting, when computers barely affected society (i am typing on a machine that has more memory than all the computers in the world in 1960s and beyond) we still worried about them having a major and negative effect on us. i sure hope skynet does not happen...

Comment: @releseabe - [Too late](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(satellite))

Comment: @Valorum: If there really were Terminators, we would probably not know this: instead of individual killing machines it would be gov officials moving us towards major disaster.

Comment: Sounds similar to the classic [The Machine Stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops), but I don't remember anything like "a cube that contains their history"

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact match but "Binary Divine" (1969) by Jon Hartridge, has some similarities. A central computer speaks to people via individual "VOICE" boxes which give them advice. Alas, the computer goes mad and only 10% of the population survive the crash. It's a novel rather than a short story, and people depend on the computer, rather than requiring permission.

Comment: _Binary Divine_ is available [on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/binarydivine0000hart) if you want to scan though to see if it's your book.